# Removing git from /usr/bin

Tags: macos, mac, git, homebrew

I'm on OS X 10.8 and I'm using Homebrew. `brew doctor` tells me that I have 2 git installations, one in `/usr/bin` and the other one in `/usr/local/bin`.

Is it a bad idea to remove git from `/usr/bin`? If no, what's the best way to remove git and the following components from `/usr/bin` to only use Homebrew's?

```
git
git-cvsserver
git-receive-pack
git-shell
git-upload-archive
git-upload-pack
gitk
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What's the best way to remove git and the following components from /usr/bin to only use Homebrew's?

Your shell uses the non-Homebrew binaries only because they come first in your `$PATH`.

So, in your `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.profile`, depending on which you use), add the following line:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Remove all other `PATH` assignments that would put `/usr/local/bin` after `$PATH`, because then, `/usr/bin` would come first, and your shell would use the system `git`.

---

You *could* remove the Git installations in `/usr/bin`, but it's up to which one to choose. I believe at some point you used the [git-osx-installer](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/), which put it there, but there's no problem keeping both installations. You just have to know which one you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to remove it using Homebrew, because it has the record that your git was installed. If you remove it manually, during some repair process, it could install it again.

With following command check what files git package is using:

```
brew info --all git
```

Or all the files with dependencies:

```
brew ls --unbrewed git
```

The the simple way is to remove it by:

```
brew remove git
```

But it's up to you.
If the git was installed by different package manager, try that one which you installed with (like port, etc.).

Comment: I'm afraid Homebrew won't work with `sudo` – there's no need to run it with root permissions anyway.

Comment: The presence of git in /usr/bin points to it being a non-Homebrew installation.

Comment: I'm using brew with sudo, but it depends of your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the "/usr/bin/git" is installed by apple git-48, so I prefer DO NOT change the PATH.
You could do something like following:

> $ brew update
>   $ brew install
>   $ sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git-48

Then you can check it by

> $ git --version

The output will be like this:
git version 2.1.0

BTW, if you want to install vim by homebrew, it also works.

Answer (score 0):

> How to remove the git installation from **/usr/local/bin** on a Mac.
>   (OSX 10.14.2)

I had an old 1.9.0 git installation from an git-osx-installer package (git-1.9.0-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg). Here's how I removed it.

Fist, find your git version and install location.

```
$ which git
/usr/local/git/bin/git
$ git --version
git version 1.9.0
```

Then, find your original git installer package, in my case git-1.9.0-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg.  If you don't have it download from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/

Finally, open the installer package (git-1.9.0-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg), and run uninstall.sh file in the root folder.

```
$ uninstall.sh
```

DONE

Attaching the uninstall.sh file, which shows the file paths being deleted.  The uninstall script may be different for different installer versions, so be sure to use the correct one.

uninstall.sh file (git-1.9.0-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg)

```
if [ ! -r "/usr/local/git" ]; then
  echo "Git doesn't appear to be installed via this installer.  Aborting"
  exit 1
fi
echo "This will uninstall git by removing /usr/local/git/**/*, /etc/paths.d/git, /etc/manpaths.d/git"
printf "Type 'yes' if you sure you wish to continue: "
read response
if [ "$response" == "yes" ]; then
  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git/
  sudo rm /etc/paths.d/git
  sudo rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
  pkgutil --packages | grep GitOSX.Installer | xargs -I {} sudo pkgutil --forget {}
  echo "Uninstalled"
else
  echo "Aborted"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply common sense and ask yourself **WHY** do you want one install removed? Do you want to invoke one of those two gits everytime? Just have its bin directory in **PATH** first.